# how to compute the projection/modelview matrix given 3D points and their 2D screen positions in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 3d, 2d

I've got a tough problem regarding the modelview/projection matrix in opengl.

Say, I have a set of 3D points, and also their corresponding 2D screen positions, is it possible to solve for the optimal modelview (or the scale/rotation/translation) matrix which transforms all these 3D points to the 2D screen positions in the least square sense, when the projection matrix is fixed? or, is it possible to solve for such a projection matrix, when the modelview matrix is fixed? Is it possible to get the parameter settings in functions such as gluperspective, gluLookAt and so on?

Comment: I guess you don't have the depth values of your 2D screen positions?

Comment: Basically, the answer is "yes".  However, there are certain things (like a uniform scale factor) that won't affect the image, so you can't get them from the 2D screen positions.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes, I just assume the depth value of the 2D screen points is 0 for example. With such 2D screen points and the positions of their corresponding 3D points, is it possible to get such a modelview matrix? or should I compute the projection matrix instead?

Comment: @comingstorm What if I fix the scale factor? With the positions of 3D points and their corresponding 2D screen points(assume their depth value is 0), is it possible to get an optimal transformation matrix?

Comment: Yes, you will need to fix elements that you can't derive.  Basically, your least-squares solver needs to enforce certain constraints anyway (e.g., to make sure the rotation matrix is a rotation matrix).  You fix things like the scale factor by adding additional constraints, so that the resulting constrained least-squares problem is well-defined.

Comment: @kyewong, it looks like you're interested in a *class* of problems here, instead of a particular, concrete problem.  Some instances are easier to deal with than others.  I would recommend reading up on computer vision methods in particular, to get a feel for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you @comingstorm . My current idea is to fix the projection matrix, and solve for the optimal modelview transformation matrix which is composed of a rotation and translation matrix. wondeing if it works or not...

Comment: Are the 3d points on the same plane when you assume depth values of 0 for the screen points?

Comment: @NicoSchertler of course not...does the z values of the screen points really matter? 'cos they are inherently 2D points projected on the screen from the 3d points...

Comment: @NicoSchertler , the z value of the screen points may really matter...how to set the a proper z value(which is one part of the target 2D screen point position) if I want to solve for such an optimal transformation matrix?

Comment: @comingstorm how to set the a proper z value(which is one part of the target 2D screen point position) if I want to solve for such an optimal transformation matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible if you have enough points.

There are libraries that can do this already check out http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html